# cannot use pod search SDWebImage to get the latest SDWebImage verison

Tags: ios, cocoapods, sdwebimage

The SDWebImage latest version in github is 3.6
But why I use the pod search SDWebImage, it gives me the latest version is only 3.5.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure master spec repo is update to date.

Go there to check:

> ~/.cocoapods/repos/master

And make sure master repo is set correct.

The offical spec repo is: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git

Answer (score 0):

Try looking on cocoapods.org, searching for SDWebImage there shows 3.7.1 as the latest version. Don't have cocoapods installed on this system to check but the search on the site should be the same. If it's not, file a bug with the cocoapods team.